# Python can generated text be converted so it can be used in code

Tags: python-2.7, list, python-imaging-library

Crop was generated from a list:

```
 count = 0
 for Crop in param:
     count = count +1
     St=chr(ord('`') + count)
     print  St,"=im.crop(",Crop,")"
```

Resulted:

```
a =im.crop( (0, 0, 640, 0) )
b =im.crop( (0, 40, 640, 40) )
c =im.crop( (0, 80, 640, 80) )
d =im.crop( (0, 120, 640, 120) )
e =im.crop( (0, 160, 640, 160) )
f =im.crop( (0, 200, 640, 200) )
g =im.crop( (0, 240, 640, 240) )
h =im.crop( (0, 280, 640, 280) )
```

I want to use the results to actually crop an image in several pieces to re-assemble using the variables with Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the eval function - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval. Or alternatively, you could save the Python code that you have generated into a file, and import/run the file.

However, either of those options are generally discouraged, because input is not always trustworthy.

I offer you the following code, which parses your code string and runs it safely - that is, it does what you expect, crops images, without opening yourself up to running any other code that may be included.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000))

input = """
a =im.crop( (0, 0, 640, 0) )
b =im.crop( (0, 40, 640, 40) )
c =im.crop( (0, 80, 640, 80) )
d =im.crop( (0, 120, 640, 120) )
e =im.crop( (0, 160, 640, 160) )
f =im.crop( (0, 200, 640, 200) )
g =im.crop( (0, 240, 640, 240) )
h =im.crop( (0, 280, 640, 280) )
"""

output = {}
for line in input.strip().split("\n"):
    variable, operation = line.split('=')

    if operation.startswith('im.crop('):
        coords = operation.split('im.crop')[1].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',')
        result = im.crop([int(coord) for coord in coords])

    output[variable.strip()] = result
print(output)
```